# Python: parallelize for loop for database query

Tags: python, multithreading, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I will break down this question into two parts.

I have code similar to this

```
for data in data_list:
  rslt = query in databae where data == 10 # just some pseudo database query to give example but this single query usually takes around 30-50seconds.
  if rslt.property == 'some condition here':
     return rslt
```

The conditions here are

1. We have to return the first element of the `data_list` that matches the condition after query.
2. Each database query for each elements take around 30-40s.
3. `data_list` is usually very big, around 15-20k elements
4. Unfortunately we can not do a single database query for whole `data_list`. We have to do this in loop or one element at a time.

Now my questions are,

1. How can I optimize this process. Currently this whole process takes around 3-4hrs.
2. I read about python threading and multiprocessing but I am confused about which one would be appropriate in this case.

Answer (score 1):

You could consider using a multiprocessing [`Pool`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.pool). You can then use [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.map) to send chunks of your *iterable* to the workers of the `Pool` to work on according to a given *function*. So, lets say your query is a function, say, `query(data)`:

```py
def query(data):
    rslt = query in databae where data == 10
    if rslt.property == 'some condition here':
        return rslt
```

We will use the pool like so:

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool

with Pool() as pool:
    results = pool.map(query, data_list)
```

Now to your rquierement we will find the first one:

```py
print(next(filter(None, results)))
```

Note that using the function `query` this way means that `results` will be a list of `rslt`s and `None`s and we are looking for the first non-`None` result.

---

A few Notes:

1. Note that the [`Pool`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.pool)'s constrctor's first argument is `processes` which allows you to choose how many processes the pool will hold:

   > If processes is `None` then the number returned by [os.cpu_count()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.cpu_count) is used.
2. Note that [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.map) has aslo the `chunksize` argument which is default to 1 and allows to choose the size of the chunks passed to the workers:

   > This method chops the iterable into a number of chunks which it submits to the process pool as separate tasks. The (approximate) size of these chunks can be specified by setting chunksize to a positive integer.
3. Continuing with `map`, the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.map) recommend using [`imap`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.imap) for large iterables with a specific chunk for better efficiency:

   > Note that it may cause high memory usage for very long iterables. Consider using [imap()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.imap) or [imap_unordered()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.imap_unordered) with explicit chunksize option for better efficiency.

   And from the `imap` [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.imap):

   > The *chunksize* argument is the same as the one used by the [map()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.map) method. For very long iterables using a large value for *chunksize* can make the job complete **much** faster than using the default value of `1`.

   So we could actually be more efficient and do:

   ```
   chunksize = 100
   processes = 10

   with Pool(processes=processes) as pool:
       print(next(filter(None, pool.imap(query, data_list, chunksize=chunksize))))
   ```

   And here you could play with `chunksize` and even `processes` (back from the `Pool`) and see what combination produces the best results.
4. If you are interested, you could easily switch to ***threads*** instead of ***processes*** by simply changing your import statement to:

   ```
   from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool
   ```

   As the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.dummy) say:

   > [multiprocessing.dummy](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.dummy) replicates the API of [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing) but is no more than a wrapper around the [threading](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#module-threading) module.

---

Hope this helps in any way

Comment: Your method loop through the complete list, how can I break the loop if first `rslt` is not `None`. If I get any result then I don't want to continue the loop.

Comment: As I mentioned in Note (3) you can use `imap` which is a lazy version of `map`. In my example we are wrapping it with `filter` which is also an iterator, and by doing `next` on that we are only working on the minimal number of chunks that will produce the first result. And also BTW there is no actual loop

Comment: @asdfkjasdfjk did you try any of the methods? did it improve timing?